# How to access each element of LiveData<List<MVoice>> with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

The Code A use `for (aMovice in listVoiceBySort.value!!)` to access each element of `LiveData<List<MVoice>>`.

But I don't think it's a good way because it uses `listVoiceBySort.value!!`, it's ugly.

Is there a good way to access each element of `LiveData<List<MVoice>>`?

**Code A**

```
 val listVoiceBySort: LiveData<List<MVoice>> =_listVoiceBySort

 fun selectAllIDs(){
   for (aMovice in listVoiceBySort.value!!){
            selectedIDs.add(aMovice.id)
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be better to use [`forEach`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html) *i.e.* an inline function with the same functionality.
It lets you use safe calls (`?.`) instead of not null assertion (`!!`):

```
fun selectAllIDs() {
    listVoiceBySort.value?.forEach {
        selectedIDs.add(it.id)
    }
}
```

Another way is to map `MVoice` elements to their ids and then add them all to the `selectedIDs`:

```
fun selectAllIDs() {
    listVoiceBySort.value?.map { it.id }?.let {
        selectedIDs.addAll(it)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally data inside a livedata is accessed via an observer where you get a non-null value

```
listVoiceBySort.observe(lifecycleOwner, Observer {
    for(mVoice in it){
    ...
    }
}
```